# How do you Synthesise a Fatty Acid Amide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

How would you go about synthesising a fatty acid amide, preferably by means of a high-yield reaction. Please provide an explanation that I, as a grade 12 chemistry graduate, could understand.

I am familiar with:

- Fatty acids
- Carboxylic acid
- Equilibrium reactions & constants
- Amide groups
- Amines
- Alkanols
- Esterification

If you need to use terms I may be unfamiliar with, it would be nice if you could explain them or provide a link to an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Schotten-Baumann Reaction

I found the solution to my question and it is the Schotten-Baumann reaction which takes an acyl chloride (which can be synthesised from a carboxylic acid via the methods detailed in the next section) and an amine to form an amide, a hydrogen chloride.

[image] (1)

[Net reaction: $ \ce{RCOCl+NH_2 R' \rightarrow RCONHR' + HCl}$]

### Synthesis of Acyl Chlorides

To create acyl chlorides from carboxylic acids the following three reactions will suffice:

$ \ce{RCOOH (l) + PCl_5 (s) \rightarrow RCOCl (aq) + POCl_3 (aq) + HCl (g) }$

$ \ce{3 RCOOH (l)+ PCl_3 (s) \rightarrow 3 RCOCl (aq) + H_2 PO_3 (aq)} $

$ \ce{RCOOH (l) + SOCl_2 (s) \rightarrow RCOCl (aq) + SO_2 (g) + HCl (g)} $

(2)

### Reference List (APA style)

1. *Schotten-Baumann Reaction Schotten-Baumann Conditions* (n.d.). Retrieved December 22 2012 from http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/schotten-baumann-reaction.shtm.
2. Clarke, J. (2004). *CONVERTING CARBOXYLIC ACIDS INTO ACYL CHLORIDES (ACID CHLORIDES)*. Retrieved December 22 2012 from http://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/acids/pcl5.html.

Answer (score 6):

You are perfectly right on that you need to convert the carboxylic acid to a more reactive species to eventually obtain the amide!

Playing with the pH will not help:

- under acidic conditions, the amine is protonated and therefore unreactive
- under alkaline conditions, the acid is deprotonated and the carboxylate won't react at all

The *Schotten-Baumann* reaction of fatty acids with $\ce{SOCl2}$ will probably work fine:

- reflux 1 mol of the acid with 1.5 mol of thionyl chloride
- dIstill the remaining thionyl chloride off
- purify the fatty acid chloride by distillation in vacuum. Note that the bp of stearoyl chloride is about 175 °C at 2 mm Hg!

This is quite some work to obtain a fatty acid derivative that eventually reacts with an amine!

**Wouldn't it be much more convenient to form the amide in a one-pot reaction, possibly at room temperature, by activating the carboxylic acid  *in situ*?**

(*In situ* means: at the same spot, without isolating the reactive intermediate.)

There's a large number of **coupling reagents** available, such as

- carbodiimides like DCC (dicyclohexylcarbodiimide)
- $1H$-benzotriazoles
- chloro-substituted triazines

*Eric Valeur* and *Mark Bradley* published a critical review titled *Amide bond formation: beyond the myth of coupling reagents*, in *Chem. Soc. Rev.*, **2009**, *38*, 606-631 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/B701677H)) on the topic.